# Skiing near Frankfurt 18-23 February

Tags: frankfurt, skiing

I will be in Frankfurt on business in February. What are the nearest ski resorts that cater for beginners and kids? Is there snow at that time of year?

Comment: I have to admit I'm surprised to find that there are quite a few ski resorts nearby, though they are all very low altitude (none go over 1000 m), so ski conditions must be very very dependent on weather, and you most probably can't be sure if there will indeed be enough snow to ski at any given date. If you want guaranteed snow you'll have to travel much further, going to the Alps in Switzerland, France or Austria.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this map:
https://www.bergfex.de/deutschland/

As you can see there are two really small ski areas in the Taunus mountain range right next to Frankfurt. But the chances of them being open while you are there are essentially 0. Note that those small areas would also usually only be open on weekends.

So this leaves you with a bit of travel. If you have a car, you can reach the Hochsauerland area (Willingen, Winterberg, Neuastenberg. Elevation 600-900m) to the North, the northern Black Forest (Mehliskopf, elevation ~1000m) to the South or the Rhön mountains (Wasserkuppe, elevation 950m) to the East within 2 hours. They should all have snow around that time. However, with climate change you never know. Willingen at the time of writing is pretty green (https://www.skigebiet-willingen.de/page/webcam.php), but they seem to be using artificial snow, so you should be able to ski the biggest slopes.

The closest ski area to surely have natural snow and some more advanced slopes would indeed be the Feldberg area in the southern Black Forest, around 4 hours by car.

All those areas are kid friendly. No dangerous slopes and lots of ski schools around. I've been there.

Answer (score 0):

You can find here [the ski resorts](https://www.skiinfo.de/hessen/skigebiete.html) in Hessen (is the State of Frankfurt), but i think there is in that time very little snow. You can go to [Feldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldberg_(Black_Forest)) in the Black Forest, which is 3 hours from Frankfurt. I think there is a lot of snow and there are very good ski resorts.

Comment: Please note that there is the (Grosser) Feldberg in the Taunus mountains, right next to Frankfurt. What sulox32 is referring to is the Feldberg in the Black Forest. It will most surely have snow whereas the Taunus one might or might not have.

Comment: Note that it takes closer to 3h30-4h (driving) and 4h30 (by train and bus) to get there from Frankfurt (according to Google Maps).

Comment: Webcams from Feldberg: https://www.liftverbund-feldberg.de/Webcams-Wetter